I am using Linux Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Anytime I launch my terminal, the image below shows up. I don't understand why
I am using Linux Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Anytime I launch my terminal, the image below shows up. I don't understand why.
When I try to make the change as per the recommendation, I get an access denied returned. I am not sure if i should go ahead an suppress the message or I really need to fix it.


Hi, welcome to [su]. Please copy & paste text rather than posting screenshots of text. How did you install zsh, and oh-my-zsh? Please edit your question and add that info.

What part of the image are you asking about exactly? The fact it’s telling you that the plugin can’t be found?

I think most of that warning is a red herring, which is why the suggested fixes don't work. It looks like you have a tiny typo in your ~/.zshrc file. This typo causes a warning and your powerlevel10k shell theme misattributes that warning to the instant prompt feature.
The key line is this one from the very end of your screenshot:
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'zhs-autosuggestions' not found
To resolve, do the following:

Open ~/.zshrc with your editor of choice
Change zhs-autosuggestions to zsh-autosuggestions (reverse the h and s)

For bonus points, you can do it on the command line:
cp ~/.zshrc ~/backup_zshrc      # just in case
sed 's/zhs-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions/' ~/.zshrc > ~/fixed_zshrc
diff ~/.zshrc > ~/fixed_zshrc   # confirm there are no unintended changes
mv -f ~/fixed_zshrc ~/.zshrc    # replace with fixed version

I hope this helps.
